# Are JSDoc @global tags ignored in modules in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am trying to make a class definition from a javascript module file be referable from all of my workspace:

```
// myclass.js

/** @global */
class MyClass {
    ...
}

export default MyClass;
```

But this is ignored by the VSCode IntelliSense (meaning that I do not get any autocomplete suggestions neither can I refer to the class by it's identifier without importing the module directly to the file).

Is this some kind of bug or limitation of VSCode, or I am doing something wrong?